# Issue in shared_preference: ^2.0.3 (latest till now 10-03-2021)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-android, flutter-sharedpreference, flutter2.0

After updating flutter I have issue in one of my project. Error Log is below. Main issue is pref not save  perfectly on device. some pref is save and some left. I checked it from fluttersharedprefs.xml

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2086)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.MethodCallHandlerImpl.commitAsync(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:137)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:96)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:340)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7853)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences( 9295):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
E/flutter ( 9295): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Task io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.MethodCallHandlerImpl$1@d8dbf46 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6e10313[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 14], null, java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.MethodCallHandlerImpl$1@d8dbf46 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6e10313[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 14]
```

**There is lot of log but due to space problem of stackoverflow I cant be able to write it....**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you file a bug report with the Flutter team in the official Flutter repo by following the instructions here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins#issues

Comment: I got it....

thank you Vladimir to suggest me to post in github. I do same but within a second some one close it and say duplicate of https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77155#issue-821268050 and when I visit it I got solution

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77155#issuecomment-790422002

Comment: @AnkushMishra Awesome that you found the solution! :)